# How can I center the picture-in-picture mode window (PiP mode)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a project in android studio with two languages ​​java and kotlin about displaying a view in my application that displays content such as video.

I would like to center an instance of the picture-in-picture mode or commonly known as picture and picture mode. Currently, when I start the instance it is created in the lower right corner, but I would like to have more control over where it appears, for example, I want it to appear at the bottom when the instance appears. center of the device screen.

What I have tried through the layout is to try to center it with **android:layout_gravity='center_horizontal'** but it didn't work, it still appears in the lower right corner.

Another option that I have tried is to add **android:layout_centerInParent='true'** but nothing and finally I tried to directly modify the code with the gravity constants of the android api but nothing...

and finally I went to the android manifest adding the label

**android:layout_gravity='center_vertical'**

This is the code I'm currently working on:

VideoPL.kt

```
    package com.sim.lyxx;

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ActivityOptions
import android.app.PictureInPictureParams
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Rational
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
import com.sim.lyxx.databinding.CustomToastBinding

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class VideoPL : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: CustomToastBinding
    private var mExoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var isPipMode: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = CustomToastBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        hideSystemUI()

        // Inicializa ExoPlayer y comienza la reproducción
        initializeExoPlayer()

        // Entra en modo PIP al iniciar la actividad
        createPIPMode()

        // Configura el listener para la visibilidad del controlador
        binding.exoPlayer.setControllerVisibilityListener { visibility ->
            val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_customPlayBackControlView)
            if (layout.tag != "IN_ANIMATION") {
                when (visibility) {
                    View.GONE -> {
                        layout.tag = "IN_ANIMATION"
                        binding.exoPlayer.showController()
                        layout.animate().alpha(0F).setDuration(450L)
                            .withEndAction({
                                binding.exoPlayer.hideController()
                                layout.tag = ""
                            }).start()
                    }
                    View.VISIBLE -> {
                        layout.animate().alpha(1F).setDuration(450L).start()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Bloquea los eventos táctiles solo cuando estás en modo Picture-in-Picture
        if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            // Retorna true para consumir los eventos táctiles y evitar que se propaguen a otras vistas
            return true
        }

        // Continúa con el comportamiento predeterminado cuando no estás en modo Picture-in-Picture
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)
    }

    private fun initializeExoPlayer() {
        mExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext).build()
        binding.exoPlayer.player = mExoPlayer
        binding.exoPlayer.useController = false
        binding.exoPlayer.hideController()
        binding.exoPlayer.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL

        val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")
        mExoPlayer!!.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        mExoPlayer!!.prepare()
        mExoPlayer!!.play()


    }

    override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean) {
        super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode)
        if (!isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            // Restaura configuración después de salir del modo PiP
            binding.exoPlayer.useController = false
            binding.exoPlayer.hideController()

        }
    }

    private fun createPIPMode() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val pictureInPictureParams = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()

                .build()

            enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParams)
        }
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (isPipMode) {
            createPIPMode()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun cancelExecution(activity: Activity) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && activity.isInPictureInPictureMode) {
                val params = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                    .setAspectRatio(Rational(16, 9))
                    .build()
                activity.setPictureInPictureParams(params)
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Actividad VideoPL cerrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                if (activity is MainActivity) {
                    // Cierra la actividad actual y reinicia la aplicación
                    val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    activity.startActivity(intent)
                    activity.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:gravity="top|start|center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exoPlayer"
        app:show_timeout="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/layout_custom_exo_player_pip"
        android:gravity="top|start|center"
        app:use_controller="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="32sp"

        android:text="View"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

android_manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".VideoPL"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >

        <layout
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:defaultHeight="100dp"
            android:defaultWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            />
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
```